# How to validate email with customized pattern with different error message using vuelidate in vue 3 composition api?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs3, vuelidate

In my vue 3 project, i am using vuelidate 2 for form validation. There is an email field which i want to validate with custom pattern.

I have created one custom email pattern using regex.

```
const emailPattern = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
```

I have created rules and set error messages for email validation. Now, i am facing issues and pattern is not working.

```
    import { useVuelidate } from '@vuelidate/core';
import { required, helpers, email } from '@vuelidate/validators';

const formData = reactive({
  data: {
    emailAddress: '',
  },
});
const rules = {
  emailAddress: {
    required,
    email: helpers.withMessage('Please enter the valid email address', email), 
  },
};
const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, formData.data);
console.log(v$.value.emailAddress.$error); // it is giving false if email field empty. It should be true
const messageType = computed(() => ((!v$.value.emailAddress.$error) ? 'warning' : ''));
const validationMessage = computed(() => ((!v$.value.emailAddress.$error) ? v$.value.emailAddress.email.$message : ''));
```

1. If i pass emailPattern instead of email then it is not working. While clicking submit button, even if email is not correctly inputted then also it is proceeding to next page.
2. If i pass email validator then it is showing that helper message and it worked but after filling the proper email that message is still visible.

**Here is my submit button**

```
    const submit = () => {
  v$.value.$validate();
  if (v$.value.$invalid) return;
  window.scrollTo(0,0); 
};
```

Please let me know what i have done wrong?

Comment: "If i pass emailPattern instead of email " -  emailPattern is not a validator. Use helpers.regex

Comment: Could you provide a *runnable* [mcve] with what you've tried? Use codesandbox.io or similar. What you shared so far is not sufficient to reproduce the described bug.